# Modify part of object in Ionic Storage

Tags: angular, typescript, ionic-framework

I'm trying to modify a part of object in Ionic storage.
I've got this in Storage:

```
key : object 
value : {a: "1", b: "2", c: "3"}
```

I tried to modify a value to 10 with this function :

```
modifyObject() {
    this.storage.get('object').then(valueStr => {
      let value = JSON.parse(valueStr);

      // Modify just that property
      value.a = '10';

      // Save the entire data again
      this.storage.set('object', JSON.stringify(value));
    });
  }
```

I've got this error when I try to execute mu function

```
ERROR Error: Uncaught (in promise): SyntaxError: Unexpected token o in JSON at position 1
SyntaxError: Unexpected token o in JSON at position 1
```

Comment: Which line is the one is failing? The JSON.parse? or the this.storage.set ?

Comment: It's the JSON.Parse

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your JSON in your value is malformed.

It must be something like this.

```
key : object 
value : {"a": "1", "b": "2", "c": "3"}
```

Comment: When I push my object like this in my Storage : `this.storage.set('object', {"a": "1", "b": "2", "c": "3"} );` , It appear without " in my Storage

Comment: Are you sure that the `this.storage.get('object')` returns an string, probably is mapping the object already.

Comment: Thaks, it work with `this.storage.set('object', JSON.stringify({a: '1', b: '2', c: '3'}));`